# GridView Fitch all data regardless of my Query Conditions?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-web-api

I have asp.net web page  with filtered search by multi text boxes when I create conditions I tested by my SQLDATASOURCE Query Builder And the result just like what I want but when I search for data by using my asp.net page all result show without regard to my conditions any one can explain why?? and my code is like that

> SQL-Query

```
SELECT        IQCRM_NUM,
              Full_name,
              Mother_Name,
              Date_of_Birth,
              Province_of_birth,
              Job
FROM    [Criminal Main Table]
WHERE   (Full_name LIKE N'%' + @Full_name + N'%') OR
        (Mother_Name LIKE N'%' + @Mother_Name + N'%') OR
        (Date_of_Birth LIKE N'%' + @Date_of_Birth + N'%')
```

> MY ASP.NET Code is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 30%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" />
        <br />
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1_NAM" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2_Mother" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3_Birth" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="IQCRM_NUM"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="IQCRM_NUM" HeaderText="IQCRM_NUM" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="IQCRM_NUM" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Full_name" HeaderText="Full_name" SortExpression="Full_name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Mother_Name" HeaderText="Mother_Name" SortExpression="Mother_Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_of_Birth" HeaderText="Date_of_Birth" SortExpression="Date_of_Birth" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Province_of_birth" HeaderText="Province_of_birth" SortExpression="Province_of_birth" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Job" HeaderText="Job" SortExpression="Job" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CriminalDBBefore2003ConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT IQCRM_NUM, Full_name, Mother_Name, Date_of_Birth, Province_of_birth, Job FROM [Criminal Main Table] WHERE (Full_name LIKE N'%' + @Full_name + N'%') OR (Mother_Name LIKE N'%' + @Mother_Name + N'%') OR (Date_of_Birth LIKE N'%' + @Date_of_Birth + N'%')">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1_NAM" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" Name="Full_name"
                    PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2_Mother" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False"
                    Name="Mother_Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3_Birth" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False"
                    Name="Date_of_Birth" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see where you are declaring and setting the variables Full_Name, Mother_Name, or Date_of_Birth. Is that being done in code behind? I recently had a similar issue where I had a search criteria with a typo and the query ran in asp.net but the results where not as expected.

Comment: @BrentOliver you can see I declare my Parameter in Selected Parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FilterParameters`  instead `SelectParameters` and add `FilterExpression` like this sample.

**SelectCommand** – Here we need to set the default SQL Query without any WHERE Clause or filter.

**FilterExpression** – Here we need to set the filter part of the SQL Query with a placeholder {0}. The placeholder {0} will be replaced by the value of the ControlParameter, i.e. the TextBox’s Text

**FilterParameters** – Here we specify the Control Parameters to be used by the FilterExpression

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CriminalDBBefore2003ConnectionString %>"
               SelectCommand="SELECT IQCRM_NUM, Full_name, Mother_Name, Date_of_Birth, Province_of_birth, Job FROM Criminal Main Table" FilterExpression="Full_name LIKE '{0}%' OR Mother_Name LIKE '{1}%' OR Date_of_Birth LIKE '{2}%'">
<FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1_NAM" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" Name="Full_name"
                          PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2_Mother" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False"
                          Name="Mother_Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3_Birth" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False"
                          Name="Date_of_Birth" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
</FilterParameters>
```

Comment: I try to use that approach but it's keep give me back all the data ??

Comment: @FarooqAlsaegh How you tested it? It should work. Put some filter text in your textboxs and rebind grid.

Comment: I did that but it's keep give me the same result